# Display time param as decoration in WMS request

Tags: geoserver, wms, parameters

Is there a way to add dynamic text decoration via a geoserver layout.xml that reflects the &time param of a geoserver WMS request?

I know from [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/animreflector.html#displaying-frame-parameters-as-decorations) how to display frame parameters as decorations for animations by using
`value="${avalue}"` in layout.xml and each animation frame shows the avalue param correctly, but for a non animation request there is no &avalue just &time and
`value="${time}"` doesn't seem to work.

Here is the layout that works for animations:

```
<layout>
  <decoration type="text" affinity="bottom,left" offset="16,6">
    <option name="message" value="Leaf Out Date: ${avalue}"/>
    <option name="font-size" value="22"/>
    <option name="font-family" value="Arial"/>
    <option name="halo-radius" value="2"/>
  </decoration>
  <decoration type="legend" affinity="bottom,right" offset="6,-6" size="0,0"/>
</layout>
```

My non animation request looks like this:

> http://myserver/geoserver/si-x/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=si-x:average_leaf_ncep_states&format_options=layout:leafout_web&styles=si-x:leafout_bimonthly&time=2016-2-18&bbox=-125.020833333333,24.0625,-66.479166666662,49.937500000002&width=1400&height=600&srs=EPSG:4269&format=image/png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem recently and by studying the source code of recent GeoServer (2.10) I found out the solution.

You can include a time-like `env` parameter in your request and then use it in your layout.

E.g.:

http://myserver/geoserver/si-x/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=si-x:average_leaf_ncep_states&format_options=layout:leafout_web&styles=si-x:leafout_bimonthly&time=2016-2-18&bbox=-125.020833333333,24.0625,-66.479166666662,49.937500000002&width=1400&height=600&srs=EPSG:4269&format=image/png&**env=the_time:2016-2-18**

```
<layout>
  <decoration type="text" affinity="bottom,left" offset="16,6">
    <option name="message" value="Leaf Out Date: ${the_time}"/>
    <option name="font-size" value="22"/>
    <option name="font-family" value="Arial"/>
    <option name="halo-radius" value="2"/>
  </decoration>
  <decoration type="legend" affinity="bottom,right" offset="6,-6" size="0,0"/>
</layout>
```

For some reason, you can't name the `env` parameter `time` (I suspect some conflict with standard WMS `time` parameter), that's why I use `the_time`.

The value is a [FreeMarker string](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html), so you can use fancy templating if you want to.